# Product Category Page | Full Width | Wordpress Woocommerce | PHP

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Initially the Product Category page is divided into

- Content Area (70% width)
- Side Bar Area (30% width)

I have removed the side bar area using function.php. However the content area is still in 70%.

I am looking for a code with the condition in php, "If the chosen url is a Product Category with two depths, then ensure the page is full width 100%".

**What is needed:** Full Width is needed for:
 - www.someexample.com/product-cateogry/firstdepth/
 - www.someexample.com/product-category/firstdepth/seconddepth/

**full width is NOT needed for:**
- www.someexample.com/product-category/firstdepth/seconddepth/thirddepth

My code are below (does not work):

**funtion.php:**

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'product_categories' );
function product_categories( $classes ) {
if (is_product_category('sanitaryware') && is_product_category('Faucet')) {
$classes[] = 'product-category';
}
// return the $classes array
return $classes;
}
```

**style.css:**

```
.ifproduct-category #content { 
width: 100%;
float: none;
}
```

Information:
WordPress | Woo-commerce | Theme name: Storefront

Comment: If you have removed the sidebar, set the width of .content-area to 100%.

Comment: @CodeRomeos if i do that, that impacts even the Single Product pages. My target is only for "Product Category" pages

Comment: Is your current site is online? if so share the URL of the page.

Comment: @CodeRomeos it should impact only the two depth which is Sanitaryware and Sanitaryware/closet

Comment: As I am getting the concern, you may need to create a custom template for full-width. And when you publish the product you can choose which template is to be selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88311/discussion-between-john-franky-and-coderomeos).

Comment: @CodeRomeos to be more clear, i need full width only to Product categories with first depth and 2nd depth, i have updated my question.